# How to add images to painted texture in blender?

Tags: blender

When painting textures in blender, I would like to add existing images to the texture image. But blender does not seem to provide such functions.

I tried external editing in photoshop, but the uv unwrapped vertices are lost and so there's no reference points available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question would be better suited to [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) and maybe a little more info on what steps you are trying.

In the image editor after you unwrap you can use UVs->Export UV Layout to save the uvs for use in an external image editor.

When using Texture painting mode you also have options to use an image as a brush texture.